# Change the value of a text field javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

Hello I am trying to understand how setting values via the chrome console work and I had success until i tried it on this site : https://www.zalando.de/login/?view=register

It wont let me fill the fields via the chrome console anyone knows why ?

```
var firstname = "Teodor"
document.getElementById("rjqNeP Upa9lO").value = firstname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are refering to the wrong element.

Try selecting the input element directly, not the wrapping div:

```
document.getElementById("text-xt7my").value = firstname
```

At the same time, you were using an ID selector trying to get a class:

```
 <div class="rjqNeP Upa9lO">
   <input id="text-xt7my" type="text" name="register.firstname" placeholder="Vorname" >
 <div>
```

In case the id is generated dynamically, refer to the class, and traverse down the DOM to find the correct input field:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("rjqNeP Upa9lO")[0].childNodes[0].value = firstname
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, but the Id changes with every refresh

Answer (score 0):

Simply select textbox by its ID = "text-1u2un"

```
document.getElementById("text-1u2un").value = firstname;
```

Comment: yes but the id changes with every refresh so I am trying to find a better way